# Query in Rails takes far more time that in MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm a little desperate. Query directly using a client as Robomongo goes smothly, but doing it in Rails takes very long (about 5 minutes). Apparently is the same query.

The query in MongoDB:

```
db.items.find({_slugs: {$in: ["gang-leader-for-a-day-a-rogue-sociologist-takes-to-the-streets"]}})
```

The query in Rails:

```
Item.in(_slugs: "gang-leader-for-a-day-a-rogue-sociologist-takes-to-the-streets").first
```

Both queries are executed on the same database and '_slugs' is indexed.

I would appreciate any help or hints.

Comment: Have you tried querying through Moped (i.e. `Item.collection.find(...)`) to bypass whatever Mongoid might be doing?

Answer (score 1):

Worked!

```
Item.collection.find({_slugs: {'$in' =>["gang-leader-for-a-day-a-rogue-sociologist-takes-to-the-streets"]}})
```

Thanks to @mu_is_too_short :)